# An index of nested subitems, indented, and hyperlinked

Tags: hyperref, indexing, nesting, xindy

## Background

Looking to indent an arbitrary n-level hierarchy within an index and have hyperlinks for the final item, using the memoir class and pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012).

For example:

```
\index[classification]{Anthropoidea!Hominoidea!Hominidae!Homo!sapiens}
```

Should produce:

[image: mockup]

Where the 2 in "sapiens, [2](http://anthro.palomar.edu/animal/table_humans.htm)" is hyperlinked back in the document (PDF).

## Problem

First, `makeindex` can only nest [3-levels deep](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/lyx/makeindex.htm#_LaTeX_Index_Commands). Second, `xindy` is incompatible with hyperref; from the man page:

> In particular, this means that by default the LaTeX package "hyperref" will create raw index files that cannot be processed with xindy. This is not a bug, this is the unfortunate result of an intented [sic] incompatibility. It is currently not possible to get both hyperref's index links and use xindy.

## Question

How would you create hyperlinked indexes that nest to an arbitrary depth?

## Example Document

A minimal document might resemble:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{style1.xdy}
(markup-index :open  "~n\begin{theindex}~n"
              :close "~n\end{theindex}~n"
              :tree)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n            \sssssubitem "  :depth 5)
\end{filecontents*}

\long\def\lettergroup#1\item{\item\textbf}
\let\lettergroupDefault\lettergroup

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Start

\index{Anthropoidea!Hominoidea!Hominidae!Homo!sapiens}

End
\printindex
\end{document}
```

However, this does not produce the correct results, when run with:

```
pdflatex file.tex; texindy file.idx; pdflatex file.tex
```

## Related Links

- [Creating an index with sub-sub-subentries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35931/creating-an-index-with-sub-sub-subentries/36001#36001)
- [Xindy: Encapsulations for Index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56826/xindy-encapsulations-for-index)
- [How can I convince hyperref and xindy to play together nicely?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80300/how-can-i-convince-hyperref-and-xindy-to-play-together-nicely)
- [How to use xindy with XeTeX/LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25623/how-to-use-xindy-with-xetex-luatex)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{style1.xdy}
(markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")

(markup-index :open  "~n\begin{theindex}~n"
              :close "~n\end{theindex}~n"
          :tree
              )
(markup-indexentry :open "~n       \sssubitem " :depth 3) 
(markup-indexentry :open "~n            \sssssubitem "  :depth 4)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n            \sssssssubitem "  :depth 5)
\end{filecontents*}

\long\def\lettergroup#1\item{\item\textbf}
\let\lettergroupDefault\lettergroup
\makeatletter
\newcommand\sssubitem{\@idxitem \hspace*{40\p@}}
\newcommand\sssssubitem{\@idxitem \hspace*{50\p@}}
\newcommand\sssssssubitem{\@idxitem \hspace*{60\p@}}

\makeatother
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Start

\index{Anthropoidea!Hominoidea!Hominidae!Homo!sapiens}


End
\printindex
\end{document}
```

You can use `hyperref` macro `\hyperpage` to link to the indexed page. With

```
(markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")
```

you tell xindy to enclose page numbers with this macro.

For more hierarchical levels, you can use

```
(markup-indexentry :open "~n       \sssubitem " :depth 3) 
(markup-indexentry :open "~n            \sssssubitem "  :depth 4)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n            \sssssssubitem "  :depth 5)
```

and define macros like `\sssubitem`:

```
\newcommand\sssubitem{\@idxitem \hspace*{40\p@}}
```

Compile with

```
pdflatex filename
texindy -M style1 filename.idx
pdflatex filename
```

You must tell `texindy` to use the module with `-M` option.

The result:

[image: hiearchical index]

Comment: @DaveJarvis není zač :)